# Reduce Processing time in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager

I am making a app, In this I am giving a feature to block calls

In this I setup a broadcast receiver to let know for incoming call, 
on receiving incoming call 
I get numbers from database, 
arranged them in array, 
and match each and every single item with the incoming call number 
if match occurs then i firstly saved the ringer mode, then I silent the phone, and then 
I disconnected call 
but it makes ring the phone for around 300-500 ms 
any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

instead of making array from database, why are you not query from DB for coming number.
Like Select from Table where number == "Coming Number" if cursor is greater then 0 means number is available. This is very fast process instead of comparing each number..

Comment: in db suppose number is saved 9999911111 and call is coming from +919999911111, so in this case, this will not work

Comment: Then in this case check with all possible use case. Like query with same coming number then number is not available then check with modified number means remove +91 if its contains.

Comment: the number can me in any form, it very very tough to match like this